# Adding a helper application to a preference pane in Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard, preferences, helper, agent

I'm developing a preference pane in 10.6 Snow Leopard and Xcode 3.2.3.

As is popular nowadays, I want to add a helper application to this preference pane. Both the application and preference pane should be able to communicate in real time (notification centre, defaults database, etc).

How would I go about doing this? I'm not sure whether to make two different projects, or make one with the pref pane and add an application as a target.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the second route; add another target to your existing project.  That way you can make the preference pane depend on the helper application, and copy the helper app into the pane's Resources folder as part of the pane's "Copy Resources" phase.

Comment: I tried that... And the app comes out empty (no related code). How do I proceed to insert a full app (with code in it)?